# How to use the output of an observable to filter another

Tags: typescript, filter, rxjs, angular2-observables

So I have two observables, one returns the current category, and the other products. I wish to filter the products based on category.

This is in Angular 2, so I really wish my ng2-view to be the subscriber (via the async pipe).

Something like this simple example:

```
let category$ = Observable.of({id: 1});
let products$ = Observable.from([{name: 'will be included', cat_ids: [1, 5]}, {name: 'nope', cat_ids: [2, 3]}, {name: 'also yep', cat_ids: [1, 7]}]);

return products$
  .toArray()
  .filter(prod => {
    return prod.cat_id.some(id => id === <how do I get the value of the category observable here?>)
  });
```

Maybe the answer is simple, but it eludes me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to join these two streams e.g. with [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest):

```
let category$ = Observable.of({id: 1});
let products$ = Observable.from([{name: 'will be included', cat_ids: [1, 5]}, {name: 'nope', cat_ids: [2, 3]}, {name: 'also yep', cat_ids: [1, 7]}]);

return Observable.combineLatest(products$, category$)
  .map(([products, category]) => {
    return products.filter(prod => prod.cat_id.some(id => id === category.id);
  });
```

**Update**

As @olsn pointed out with `Observable.from` you get stream of events not stream of array of events. Hence the solution should be:

```
let category$ = Observable.of({id: 1});
let products$ = Observable.from([{name: 'will be included', cat_ids: [1, 5]}, {name: 'nope', cat_ids: [2, 3]}, {name: 'also yep', cat_ids: [1, 7]}]);

return Observable.combineLatest(products$, category$)
  .filter(([product, category]) => {
    return product.cat_id.some(id => id === category.id);
  })
  .map(([product, category]) => product);
```

Comment: Just in case someone else is coming across this solution: `products$` is using `Observable.from` -> so `products` will __not__ be an array, but a single object, so the code as it is will fail with `products.filter is not a function`

Comment: Observable.from accepts an array in rxjs 5. So the code would work, I'd think.

Comment: Ah I get what you mean. You can put the toArray() operator in the middle to make it into an array if needed.

Comment: @DarkNeuron, Yes you can. Also you can use `of` instead of `from`. But in both cases you will get stream of array. And it can be undesirable.